# Wit.ai How to Get an whole sentence in an entity

Tags: wit.ai, wit-ai

I would like to store an entire sentence an user said and store it.
[image]

This his how I did but I can't get the sentence from A to Z an an whole entity, just few parts knows as "number", "location", ....

```
merge(request) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var entities = request.entities;
        var context = request.context;
        var message = request.message;
        var sessionId = request.sessionId;

        var intent = firstEntityValue(entities, 'intent');

        if (intent == "write_free_text") {
            context.free_text = request["text"];
        }
        if (intent == "choose_city") {
            var city = firstEntityValue(entities, 'location');
            context.city = city;
        }
        return resolve(context);
    });
}
```

**How can I do that and store the whole sentence with merge function ?** Thank you

Comment: Try to get the `message` in your `merge` method. I think for this case you don't need use intent

Comment: I tried "wit/message_body", "wit/phrase_to_translate" and others but it always cut my sentence or cause bad behaviors ! I can't get back all the sentence from A to Z without wit interpretations !! Very annoying, any help will be appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the whole sentence, maybe you don't needs a entity, just get the message sent:

```
// Merge action
function merge(request) {
  context.freetext = request["text"];
  return context;
}
```

Bot: https://wit.ai/Godoy/bottest/stories/4da2840f-513e-42ed-a494-c5516c07242e

Fiddle with code: https://wit-ai.github.io/witty-fiddle/?id=e4c16a624c87d37f9c0c29d8299ca5fc

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my initial question. I tried without entity and I did like you said. But there are a lot of troubles ! Here is what I get back when I write my free text  : `{"distance":[{"confidence":1,"type":"value","value":123123}],"intent":[{"confidence":0.8779698641320263,"value":"choisir une date"}]}`. So, the "write_free_text" is not recognized and I can't get "request["text"]" back.

Comment: Ok, so I tried and I succeed like you said ! But with this "method" Wit failed to recognize the intent "write_free_text" so I had to do like that : `if(!intent) {
 context.text = request["text"];
}` . Thank you again ! I accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the whole phrase, use the **wit/phrase_to_translate** built-in entity

Comment: A code example would improve this answer quite a lot.

Comment: With "wit/phrase_to_translate" Wit always cuts my sentence ! I can't get it back from A to Z

Answer (score 0):

[a snapshot of the uunderstanding tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8UIz.jpg)

you just have to train the bot, once or twice.
It will pick up all the free text later.

Comment: I tried more than twice but it always cut the whole sentence ! It removed sometimes the first word and keep the rest